# How to make typehint for method responses, where responses depend on method parameters in python?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, typing, python-typing

## My intention

So, I am developing an API package for one service. I want to make good typehints for every method, which exists in my library

For example, when user types `get().`, after the dot pycharm will let him know, what response this method will provide.

e.g:

```
info = get()

info.  # and here IDE help with hints.
```

### Pitfalls

But, there are some methods, which provide different responses depending of parameters in methods.
e.g.

```
# this method responses with object, containing fields:
#     count - count of items
#     items - list of ids of users
info = get()


# but this method will give additional information. It responses with object, containing fields:
#     count - count of items
#     items - list of objects with users' information. It has fields:
#         id - id of user
#         firstname - firstname of user
#         lastname - lastname  of user
#         ... and some others
info = get(fields='firstname')
```

### Objects structure

Now I have such structure (i't simplified)

```
from typing import List, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class UserInfo(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(...)
    firstname: str = Field(None)
    lastname: str = Field(None)
    some_other_fields: str = Field(None)


class GetResponseNoFields(BaseModel):
    count: int = Field(...)
    items: List[int] = Field(...)


class GetResponseWithFields(BaseModel):
    count: int = Field(...)
    items: List[UserInfo] = Field(...)

class GetResponseModel(BaseModel):
    response: Union[GetResponseNoFields, GetResponseWithFields] = Field(...)


def get(fields=None) -> GetResponseModel:
    # some code
    pass
```

### The problem

The problem is, when I type `get(fields='firsttname').response.items[0].` pycharm shows me typehints only  for `int`. He doesn't think, that items can contain `List[UserInfo]`, he thinks, it only can have `List[int]`

---

#### I have tried

I've tried to use typing.overload decorator, but method 'get' has many parameters, and actually doesn't support default parameter values. Or maybe i didn't do it properly

Here what I have tried with overload (simlified). It didn't work because of 'some_other_param', but I leave it here just in case:

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def get(fields: None) -> GetResponseNoFields: ...
@overload
def get(fields: str) -> GetResponseWithFields: ...
def get(some_other_param=None, fields=None):
    # code here
    pass
```

When I try to call method without parameters, pycharm says, that "Some of the parameters is unfilled"

Comment: The full signature should be repeated in every overload